# Single Sign On (SSO) with LinkedIn as SP. How Log users into LinkedIn automatically?

Tags: single-sign-on, linkedin-api, saml, saml-2.0

my question relates to how to log users into LinkedIn (SP) automatically from a company web portal that I am making. (As opposed to how to authenticate user on my website using linked in as the IdP).

I need my website users to be able to configure their LinkedIn account username and be automatically logged in to LinkedIn when they click the LinkedIn icon. I achieved this with Sales Force by use of an uploaded certificate and a SAML token and ideally would be able to use a similar approach with LinkedIn.

Is this possible? Has anyone else managed to achieve this and what is the best approach?